# work with array in object array

Tags: c#, arrays, object

How can i work with Array in Object Array

Please see picture for more info :

[image]
[image]
I use from forech for get Object and then i want to work with Array in Object but it's not possible

```
foreach (object element in result)
```

I want to get value from array and work with them for example i want to get "TestCategory_1" or etc but i can't

now how can i work with value like this ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that `element`s from `result` are of type [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx).
Try with this:

```
foreach (IDictionary element in result)
{
    var testCategory = element["categoryName"];
}
```